# I want to get event @click from javascript create element with DOM on vue.js(nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

HTML

```
<button @click="createEle()" id="btn1">click</button>
```

vue

```
methods: {
   createEle() {
      let aEle = document.createElement("a")
      aEle.classList.add("btn2")
      aEle.innerHTML = "Button 2";
      document.body.appendChild(aEle)
   },
   getBtn2() {
      console.log(document.querySelector('.btn2').innderHTML)
   }
}
```

result my code after click Button #btn1

```
<button id="btn1">click</button>
<a class="btn2">Button 2</a>
```

but How to create @click insert to .btn2 for call function getBtn2()

Answer (score 2):

In template:

```
   <button @click="createEle()" id="btn1">click</button>
   <a v-for="link in links" :href="link.href" class="btn2">{{link.text}}</a>
```

In script:

```
    data(){
      return {
          links: [],
      }
    },
    methods:{
      createEle() {
        let newLink = { href: "https://www.google.com/", text: "Google" } ;
        this.links.push(newLink);
      },
      getBtn2() {
         this.links.forEach(el => console.log(el.text) );
      }
    }
```