# how to query a css selector with an attribute name starting with '@'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, console.log

I use `$('div[@click="login()"]')` to select

```js
<div @click="login()"> Login </div>
```

but it gives

```
VM353:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': 'div[@click="login()"]' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

what is the correct way?

Comment: I don't think that's valid css.

Comment: Can you give it another, valid selector?

Comment: @chovy if it's a regular css then it would be easy, i won't ask question here :-P

Comment: @fubar no, xpath is not possible because i found the xpath to the element is not fixed. that's why i tried css selector but it's not valid. if querySelector is impossible may be i have to use `innerText`?

Comment: can't you add a class or id to it?

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid HTML.

You commented on another answer with links to "[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472041/how-to-change-dynamically-the-click-method-in-vue), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566868/i-want-to-get-event-click-from-javascript-create-element-with-dom-on-vue-jsnux) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73278851/how-can-i-use-click-event-with-option-vue)". Those are all questions about vue.js, a templating language that transpiles to (produces) HTML. Other templating languages include EJS, Pug, Handlebars, React, and Angular.

If you are really using vue.js in your project, you should add the [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) tag to this question and future questions related to it.

The `@click` attribute is only meaningful to Vue, and it will not be present in the actual HTML on the webpage. Vue might turn it into an `onclick` handler, so you could try using `$('div[onclick="login()"]')` which might return you the element you want.

Otherwise, give your div an id too:

```
<div id="login-button" @click="login()"> Login </div>
```

And select on that id: `$('#login-button')`

Comment: It's "invalid" only because `<html:DIV>` doesn't have a declared `@click` attribute, but the same would be true for the `click` attribute. The `@` character doesn't make it invalid HTML. `<my-div @click="login()"></my-div>` is perfectly valid HTML (even though it won't be serializable as XML 1.0)